# how to import a relationship file into Neo4j to create relationship between existing labels?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and have been trying to import a relationship file using Cypher to create a relationship between two existing labels. I have a file with relationship

```
EID,CID
1,1
1,3
2,5
2,7
```

I also have two existing labels in Neo4j with employee and children.

```
 Employee file has
 eid, name, salary

 Children file has
 cid, name, age
```

I am trying to import the relationship file so that I can create a relationship between employee and children using the eid and cid.

So far I have tried

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT                                                                                                 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/c:/SKR/links.csv' AS row                   
MATCH(f:Emps{eid: toInt(row.from_Emps_eid)}), (t:Children{cid: 
toInt(row.to_Children_cid)})                           
CREATE (f)-[:CHILD]->(t);
```

I am getting no rows, no changes. I would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You CSV file's header row specifies these names: `EID`, `CID`. In your query, use those names (instead of `from_Emps_eid` and `to_Children_cid`, respectively):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT                                                                                                 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/c:/SKR/links.csv' AS row                   
MATCH(f:Emps{eid: toInt(row.EID)}), (t:Children{cid: toInt(row.CID)})                           
CREATE (f)-[:CHILD]->(t);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to remove the toInt and then it worked!

Comment: a follow-up query question.
I am trying to find the employee with the highest salary and I used the following commond Match(e:Emps) return max(salary), e.name. 
the return gives me all the employee and all the salaries. I know I can do this in two separate commands but is there a way to do it in one command?

Comment: Assuming `salary` is an `Emps` property: `MATCH (e:Emps) RETURN e ORDER BY e.salary DESC LIMIT 1`.